# where to find my android new internal file

Tags: android, android-studio, fileoutputstream, internal-storage

I am trying to save a string input from the user (called editServer) into a internal file with:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                EditText server = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editServer);
                Log.i("Settings", server.getText().toString());

                String filename = "ServerURL.txt";
                String serverurl = server.getText().toString();
                FileOutputStream outputStream;

                try {
                    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write(serverurl.getBytes());
                    Log.i("Write",serverurl+" saved to "+filename);
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            });
```

My issue is that after that I can't find this file. Where is it?
I tried opening the Android Device Monitor with Android Studio but I can't find the folder. I tried to get the string using:

```
        fis = context.openFileInput("ServerURL.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        return line;
```

But it returns null, which makes me believe that I am making a mistake. Am I creating the file properly or is there some issue in my code?

Thank you.

---

**Update**

Android device monitor -> File explorer will let you see and find where your file is.

Comment: "Where is it?" -- that depends on what user account is running your app. And, if you are testing on hardware, you do not have direct access to the location anyway, except perhaps on rooted devices. See: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html

Comment: It is a rooted device. I will check the link, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to return `sb.toString()` instead of `line`.